# How to make Ubuntu auto unlock disk keystore-rpool with TPM?

Tags: boot, encryption, tpm

So i chose Ubuntu 22.04 to be installed with ZFS and encryption, but turns out it requires me to always manually enter the password to "unlock disk keystore-rpool".

How to make Ubuntu auto unlock disk keystore-rpool with TPM?

like how Windows auto unlock bitlocker with TPM